# Steps to Configure the Clustering and Load balancing with Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I recently learned the difference between **Clustering** and **Load balancing**.

I have an chat application and I need it to test with the load balancing and clustering.

I googled a lot and can't get an exact answer .

I don't know how to configure this with tomcat.

Hope our Stack users will give the best answer and will give the configuration steps and required servers and files for me.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat clustering typically means session replication - something that might not be what you expect when you have a chat application that is deployed on two servers. I'm afraid, I expect you will have to explicitly code some business-layer code to be able to have user 1, connected to tomcat 1, being able to chat to user 2 on tomcat 2.

Configuring [tomcat as a cluster](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) will help your loadbalancer to balance requests from tomcat 1 to tomcat 2 in the event that tomcat 1 will fail (typically the user continues to be logged in in a tomcat cluster installation). But it won't do anything to help your chat to be magically distributed between the two servers.

I'm suspecting that this is what got you puzzled - it seems to be something different compared to what you're looking for. (I'm only guessing this based on the little bit of information that you give)

I'm afraid, I don't expect anybody to provide configuration files that will magically work (or I misinterpreted your question)

Comment: Thank for your reply... This is  the scenario told by my TL .I have 2 severs running and handling the request from user.If any one server fails and the request will be handled by another server with out any data loss.What to do for that?

Comment: Also how to perform the load balancing ?

Comment: If your load balancer only ever balances to one of the two tomcats (instead of keeping both busy), http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html will help (the link given in the answer). If it balances to both tomcat's simultaneously as long as they are there, my answer holds